# I want to fetch max and min past temperature of US on the basis of ZipCode using NCDC (National Climate Data Center)climate Data API

Tags: java, rest, api, web-services, restful-url

I am using [this](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&datatypeid=TMAX,TMIN&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-02) API for fetching data:

> https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&datatypeid=TMAX,TMIN&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-02

It returns the following response:

```js
{
  "metadata": {
    "resultset": {
      "offset": 1,
        "count": 4,
          "limit": 25
    }
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "date": "2010-05-01T00:00:00",
      "datatype": "TMAX",
      "station": "GHCND:USW00013872",
      "attributes": ",,0,2400",
      "value": 267
    },
    {
      "date": "2010-05-01T00:00:00",
      "datatype": "TMIN",
      "station": "GHCND:USW00013872",
      "attributes": ",,0,2400",
      "value": 139
    },
    {
      "date": "2010-05-02T00:00:00",
      "datatype": "TMAX",
      "station": "GHCND:USW00013872",
      "attributes": ",,0,2400",
      "value": 267
    },
    {
      "date": "2010-05-02T00:00:00",
      "datatype": "TMIN",
      "station": "GHCND:USW00013872",
      "attributes": ",,0,2400",
      "value": 206
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot find the document regarding the attributes of the response, Is there any other way I can get such info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this [link](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation) has the information you are looking for. Please note that this information is provided by NCDC. You need to contact them for information. Most likely all necessary information will be available in their website. You just need to look out carefully.